# how to add a plot function in ionic with higcharts?

Tags: ionic-framework, highcharts, ionic2

so i'm doing an app in ionic 2 like geogebra so for example if i want to graph a lineal or quadratic equation i will use the function 'y = mx + b' and the user can modify only 'm' and 'b' and show this graphic.
so do you have any ideas that can show me.?
I'll be eternally grateful (:

Comment: You can make a simple function that will return a bunch of points linearly or quadratic. I.e. `function linearPoints(xAxis, m, b) { return xAxis.map(function(x) { return [x, x*m + b]}); });` where xAxis is an array of xAxis points. Which would return a data array with `[[x, y], [x, y], ...]`.

Comment: As an complement to the above comment I can add that you can use `Point.update` (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update) on all points when the user changes the value of `m` or `b`.